# How to delete item from database?

Tags: java, angular, typescript

I configured a button to delete an item from my database when i select it , and it doesn't call my deleteFunction i don't understand why . The button works , it does the other function , but the deleteFunction does nothing .

This is the typescript code :

```
delete() {
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([...this.dataSource.data.filter(p => {
  if (this.selection.isSelected(p)) {
    this.selection.toggle(p);

  this.patientRestService.deletePatient(p.id.toString());
    return false;
  }
  return true;
})]);
  }

 deletePatient(id){
return this.http.delete<any>('http://localhost:8080/patient/delete?id=' + id);
   }
```

And this is the java code for server and commands :

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/patient/delete")
public void deleteClient(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
    if (this.patientRepository.existsById(id)) {
        this.patientRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is not Javascript ...

Comment: @AKSW Where did he write that?

Comment: it is not Javascript , is the java part for the backend

Comment: @akaMishu does your endpoint gets triggered?

Comment: I think you have to subscribe to your `deletePatient()`.

Comment: Just as an FYI, but this pattern of `existsById` and `deleteById` actually creates a race condition. When you run that in a concurrent setting, someone could delete the entity in between calls. IMHO it's a mistake that the Spring Data JPA API throws an exception here at all, it should instead return a Boolean. You could load the entity and then call `repo.delete(entity)`, which doesn't throw AFAIK. But that is more expensive.

Comment: If you look at the implementation of `deleteById`, you can see that it actually doesn't do a JPQL Bulk Delete, but instead it does a `findById`, followed by a `delete`, or else a throw. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/879f3b317de86c09d98316a7dae35f78353fe2f2/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L171

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `deletePatient()` call to this:

```
this.patientRestService.deletePatient(p.id.toString()).subscribe(response) => doSomething());
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks i forgot the subscribe ! :)